# How does one safely pass a url and filename as part of a query string?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a url: `http://foo.com`

Normally if I wanted to pass any parameters to it I would do something like:

```
http://foo.com?param1=car&param2=red
```

But what if I wanted to pass a url and filename instead ? 
I can't just do this:

```
http://foo.com?url=http://bar.com/kitty.jpg&filename=kitty.jpg
```

Because there are a number of characters that I might have to escape. I create the url in javascript, so I can use the Javascript API to construct the url. Any suggestion on how to do this, and which pitfalls to watch out for ? How to safely create the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) - simple example:

```
var url='http://bar.com/kitty.jpg';
var filename='kitty.jpg';

var completeUrl='http://foo.com'+
   '?url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+
   '&filename='+encodeURIComponent(filename);
```

Comment: what happens when the var url will contain another & and ?

Comment: that's precisely why you escape them like this

Comment: What about : " ' "
I believe that encodeurlcomponent does not escape " ' ". Does it matter ?

Comment: ah yes, it behaves bit differently than regular encodeURI: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp